# Problem fetching data in the loop (Scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new with scrapy and one of my spider is getting me troubles. I would like some help to figure out what´s wrong in my code. I am looping a table after following some URLs and the loop get all the  rows but just get the data from the first row.

This is my code:

```
 def parse(self, response):
    Caballo = response.url
    jockey_url = response.xpath(
            './/*[@id="site-content"]/div/main/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a/@href').get()
    loader = ItemLoader(item=DailyItem(), response=response)
    loader.add_value('Caballo', Caballo)
    loader.add_xpath('jockey', './/*[@id="site-content"]/div/main/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a/text()')
    new_items = loader.load_item()
    yield response.follow(jockey_url, self.parse_jockey, meta={'item': new_items})

def parse_jockey(self, response):

    new_items = response.meta['item']
    table = response.xpath('//*[@id="tab-form-alltime"]/div/table/tbody/tr')

    for t in table:
        loader = ItemLoader(item=new_items, selector=t)
        loader.add_xpath('Type', './/td[1]/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('Rate', './/td[6]/text()')

        yield loader.load_item()
```

This is the output from one of the Urls, as you can see, there are 3 rows which is fine but the same
data on it:

```
{"Caballo": "https://www.attheraces.com/form/horse/Alexanderthegreat/FR/3022995?raceid=1149928", "jockey": "Jason Hart", "Type": "Flat Turf", "Rate": "11.57%"},
{"Caballo": "https://www.attheraces.com/form/horse/Alexanderthegreat/FR/3022995?raceid=1149928", "jockey": "Jason Hart", "Type": "Flat Turf", "Rate": "11.57%"},
{"Caballo": "https://www.attheraces.com/form/horse/Alexanderthegreat/FR/3022995?raceid=1149928", "jockey": "Jason Hart", "Type": "Flat Turf", "Rate": "11.57%"},
```

This is what the bucle has to to fetch:

[Fetch column1(Type) and column6 (Strike rate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0yPf.png)

Answer (score 0):

So I think the thrust of the problems are your XPATHs.

### Code Example test.py

```
import scrapy
from ..items import DailyItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'test'
        allowed_domains = ['www.attheraces.com']
        start_urls = ['https://www.attheraces.com/form/jockey/Jason-Hart/1354728?raceid=1149928']

    def parse(self, response):
        Caballo = response.url
        
        jockey_url = 'https://www.attheraces.com/form/horse/Strongbowe/FR/3091730?raceid=1150331'
        loader = ItemLoader(item=DailyItem(), response=response)
        loader.add_value('Caballo', Caballo)
        loader.add_xpath('Jockey', '//h1[@class="h3"]/text()')
        new_items = loader.load_item()
    
        yield response.follow(jockey_url, self.parse_jockey, meta={'item':new_items})

    def parse_jockey(self, response):
        
    
         
        table = response.xpath('//div[@id="tab-form-flat-form"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr')
        new_items = response.meta['item']
        for t in table:
            loader = ItemLoader(item=new_items, selector=t)
            if t.xpath('.//td[1]/div/span[2]/text()'):
                loader.add_xpath('Type', './/td[1]/div/span[2]/text()')
                loader.add_xpath('Rate', './/td[6]/text()')
                yield loader.load_item()
            else: 
                continue
```

### Code Example items.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst

class DailyItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    Caballo = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    Jockey = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    Type = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    Rate = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
```

### Output

```
{"Caballo": "https://www.attheraces.com/form/jockey/Jason-Hart/1354728?raceid=1149928", "Jockey": "Jason Hart", "Type": "Turf", "Rate": "50.0%"}
```

### Tips

1. If there's a class or id attribute for the HTML tag you're trying to extract trying using that instead to get the information instead of a long list of divs in your XPATH.

2.For long attribute names use the contains function in XPATH which will grab any attribute which
contains whatever you specify.

For example

```
   '//div[contains(@class,"jock")]'
```

Would grab any div where the class attribute has jock in it.

3. Use scrapy shell to validate your XPATH selectors before writing your code. Saves a lot of time trying to figure out whether you're getting the data you want.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer and thanks for the tip, very useful, I will use it from now on. The correction gives this output:
  File "C:\Users\xshel\Documents\python\pruebas3\daily\spiders\Jockey.py", line 36, in parse_jockey
    loader = ItemLoader(item=new_items(), selector=t)
Regarding the URL is taken from a file with a list of URLS created by other spider. You can see in the example through "Caballo" item which URL is coming from and in this example this is the current scraped URL: 
[link](https://www.attheraces.com/form/jockey/Jason-Hart/1354728?raceid=1149928)

Comment: I've tried replicating your code, couldn't get the jockey_url with your XPATH. When I found the possible url. I couldn't replicate parse_jockey function  table variable XPATH using this url (https://www.attheraces.com/form/horse/Alexanderthegreat/FR/3022995?raceid=1149928). Have you made sure your XPATHs are correct in the scrapy shell ? I always do this before commiting to my scrapy script.

Comment: Make sense, after each race in the horse profile the jockey link is gone cause maybe in the next race there is another jockey so you can try with a horse in a future race, try with this one: [link](https://www.attheraces.com/form/horse/Strongbowe/FR/3091730?raceid=1150331)

Comment: Can I ask why use two different classes in your items.py ? Are you trying to fill the two item dictionaries with two seperate class ? Struggling to see your logic here. I've managed to output I think what you desire using your two classes in items.py. See https://pastebin.com/iEJQVdKS. You definitely need to check your XPATH though, use the scrapy shell to make sure you're grabbing what you desire. Using the url you give.

Comment: If you refer to new_items, this is a variable to store the values from def parse and take them to def parse_jockey results that is the reason to `loader=Itemloader(item=new_items,selector=t)` to have the same output line with data of 2 differents URLS  but in items.py there is just one class. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yep I do, I now get why you choose new_items. Just writing up the code now. Just updated my answer with code.

Comment: Thank you for your response and correction, my items.py is the same that you posted and I changed the spider code but it doesn´t work and I don´t get these xpaths:
  
`if t.xpath ('.//td[1]/div/span[2]/text()'):
    loader.add_xpath('Type', './/td[1]/div/span[2]/text()')`  
there is no div tag after td so a little confuse about this.

Comment: I've just rerun the code I have. Seems that my XPATH selectors are working and I get the output you see in my answer. I hope that is the output you are looking for ?. Could you paste your code into http://pastebin.com/ exactly the way you have it in your code editor. It may be something minor.